# regex expression obtaining integer after string

Tags: regex

I am stuck writing a regex expression in JavaScript, which I'm sure is pretty basic but I'm struggling to get my head around it.

Basically I need to grab just the integers after a string in a url and store the answer into a variable. For example:
www.examplepage.com/?0,1,3,north12

So from that url I need to grab just the integers after the string "north", yet when I do it I can only seem to return "north12" rather than "12".

The regex I have so far is: `/north(\d+)/`

Comment: We can't see your current regex unless you post it in your question...

Comment: use a capturing group

Comment: I've added my regex

Comment: you can use :    /\?.*\W?[a-z]+(\d+)/   and capture first group

Comment: The regex looks correct (for some dialects of regex) but you are probably using it incorrectly.  Show your actual code (and add the appropriate tags to your question).  For example, in Perl, `m/north(\d+)/ and say "$1"` would extract the captured group.

Comment: This will take all the numbers at the end of your string (\d+)$

Comment: @rebeccasmith_me my answer gives correct output. I have just edited it.

Comment: @rebeccasmith_me By "appropriate tags", triplee was implying that we need to know what computer language you are using.

Comment: @xenteros Thank you for your answer, I just tried it on http://regexr.com/ and it says lookbehind is not supported by JavaScript. This is to be used with JavaScript and I want to extract just the number after the word north and store it into a variable. I cannot paste code yet as I haven't written it I am just trying to get the right regex expression first then write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following java statement will return just a number. It uses positive lookahead assertion.

```
    String s = "www.examplepage.com/?0,1,3,north12";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?<=north)[0-9]+" );
    Matcher m = p.matcher( s );
    if ( m.find() ) {
        System.out.println(m.group().toString());
    }

>>12
```

The regex is `(?<=north)[0-9]+`

The walkaround in java script will be:

```js
function removeLeadingCharacters(string){
  return string.replace(/.*north(?=[0-9]+)/g, ""); // $& means the whole matched string
};
function revStr(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
function removeTrailingCharacters(string){
  return revStr(revStr(string).match(/[0-9]+$/g, " ")[0]); // $& means the whole matched string
};

window.alert(removeTrailingCharacters(removeLeadingCharacters("asdadasdnorth12asda")));
```

This will print the number only. You can take it into a variable. Remember to escape your `"`s when declaring string for debug!

Comment: Here is a basic example of what I am trying to achieve. Yet i can only obtain north1 and for some reason the output is north1,1? 
'<body>
  <a id="aaa" href="www.example.com/?1,2,3,north1">Link</a>
 </body>
 <script>
  var text = document.getElementById("aaa").getAttribute("href");
  var UKLocation = text.match(/north(\d+)/);
 </script>'